# Screen not repainted until function completed

Tags: javascript

Please look at the following code:

```
...
$(document.documentElement).append("<div id='suggestContainer'>Loading...</div>");
$("#suggestContainer").css({
    border: "1px solid black",
    position: "absolute",
    display: "block",
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    height:100
});
//alert("test");
TimeConsumingFunction();
...
```

**The problem:** suggestContainer element won't display in the document until TimeConsumingFunction call is completed. If I uncomment alert(test) before TimeConsumingFunction call, alert dialog shows up and I can see suggestionContainer element displayed.

Why is this happening? I tried IE and Chrome and it works the same.
Is there way to flush HTML and force changes to be displayed?

Thanks

Comment: First of, why don;t you do `$("body").append()` instead of that weird document.documentElement you are doing? Secondly, what is your timeconsuming function doing to consume time?

Comment: because he is not using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you are appending the div and just after that adding the css so may be it is not loaded to DOM properly.After css added use `setTimeout` for a sec then call `TimeConsumingFunction();` or use the css in the div itself i.e. inline.

```
setTimeout(function(){ TimeConsumingFunction() },100);
```